# WebDriver: Can I inject a jQuery script for a page that isn't using jQuery?

Tags: selenium2, webdriver, javascript

Is it possible to inject a jQuery script into a page if the page isn't already using jQuery?  We have a few pages in our sites where we don't add jQuery if it doesn't need it, but I'm using it to automate the page with WebDriver.  I don't want to test my JavaScript on every browser just for these pages.

Example usage of jQuery code:

```
public static long GetLongValueViaJQuery(IWebDriver driver, string jQueryCode)
{
    IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
    return (long)js.ExecuteScript("return " + jQueryCode);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using jQuery with selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but in theory it should work.  You can use javascript like this to load new js files into memory:

`var scriptElt = document.createElement('script');
scriptElt.type = 'text/javascript';
scriptElt.src = jsFile;
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptElt);`

You would need to load all of the jquery javascript libraries and then you would be able to call the jqeury functions as you listed above.

Comment: Unless you load jQuery from the same domain as your webapp, you may run into this problem: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/inconsistent-results-when-capturing-javascript-errors-with-webdriver.

Comment: Again, I haven't tested it, but I'm pretty sure the jquery javascript library employs domain lowering to work in this case.  Very true that this could cause problems for a lot of .js files though.

Comment: basically, avoid linking a filen then just execute the script content, so the cross-domain problem will be never on your context.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a script which loads jQuery through WebDriver.  I've been using it successfully for quite some time.

#### Features:

-- will not overwrite any existing jQuery instance.
-- will not alter the DOM under test or pollute the global namespace
-- cleans up after itself to avoid memory leaks
-- waits for jQuery to be fully loaded before returning.
-- takes an optional parameter specifying a jQuery source (defaults to version 1.7.2 from Google's CDN).
-- cross-browser compatible

#### The Script:

You must pass this as a string to [`IJavaScriptExecutor.ExecuteAsyncScript`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_IJavaScriptExecutor_ExecuteAsyncScript.htm):

```js
/** dynamically load jQuery */
(function(jqueryUrl, callback) {
    if (typeof jqueryUrl != 'string') {
        jqueryUrl = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
    }
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var done = false;
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = (function() {
            if (!done && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'loaded' 
                    || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
                done = true;
                script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = null;
                head.removeChild(script);
                callback();
            }
        });
        script.src = jqueryUrl;
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    else {
        callback();
    }
})(arguments[0], arguments[arguments.length - 1]);
```

#### Example Usage (Java):

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

/**
 * An example of loading jQuery dynamically using WebDriver.
 */
public class Test {

    // its nice to keep JavaScript snippets in separate files.
    private static final String JQUERY_LOAD_SCRIPT = "resources\\jQuerify.js";

    // driver
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        String jQueryLoader = readFile(JQUERY_LOAD_SCRIPT);

        // give jQuery time to load asynchronously
        driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeAsyncScript(jQueryLoader /*, http://localhost:8080/jquery-1.7.2.js */);

        // ready to rock
        js.executeScript(
            "jQuery(function($) { " +
                " $('input[name=\"q\"]').val('bada-bing').closest('form').submit(); " +
            " }); "
        );
    }

    // helper method
    private static String readFile(String file) throws IOException {
        Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, cs));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            char[] buffer = new char[8192];
            int read;
            while ((read = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
                builder.append(buffer, 0, read);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        }
        finally {
            stream.close();
        }        
    }
}
```

#### Credits:

I adapted this script from the excellent [jQuerify bookmarklet](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/04/better-stronger-safer-jquerify-bookmarklet) by Karl Swedberg.

Comment: I was writing a comment about that is not the same to link a file or url then raise the cross-domain problem, than just inject the content of that file directly :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my extension method I am using with WatiN

The parameter Browser – is WatiN’s browser object.

And also, WitiN required to pass the JavaScript code as a single line. That is why you can see .Replace("\r\n", ""); in the code:

```
    public static void InjectJQuery(this Browser browser)
    {
        string injectjQuery2 = @"
               function loadScript(scriptUrl) 
               {
                   var head =  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                   var script = document.createElement('script');
                   script.type = 'text/javascript';
                   script.src = scriptUrl;
                   head.appendChild(script);
               }
               loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js');
               loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js');
               ".Replace("\r\n", "");

        browser.Eval(injectjQuery2);
    }
```

Comment: Clean solution, I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it works in Ruby:'

```
      # test.rb
      require 'selenium-webdriver"
      @browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
      @browser.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"
      dir_to_jquery = Dir.pwd + '/features/support/ajax_resources'
      # jQuerify.js is the same java script posted above by Joe Coder
      jquerystring = File.open("#{dir_to_jquery}/jQuerify.js").read

      #Give time for script to load and inject jquery library dynamically
      @browser.manage.timeouts.script_timeout = 10
      @browser.execute_async_script(jquerystring)
      @browser.execute_script("jQuery(function($) { " +" $('input[name=\"q\"]').val('pradeep@seleniumframework.com').closest('form').submit(); " +" }); ");
```

Answer (score -1):

I am seeing one issue in this. I am getting "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: jQuery is not defined" exception on executing js.executeAsyncScript(jQueryLoader);

Comment: This looks like a commentary on the post and not an actual answer to the question.  Plus this is a very old question you are answering.  Consider elaborating a bit further.